# What's the name of this operation?

Tags: exponential-function

definition (N$\times$N)$\Rightarrow$N

(n,m)=n^n^...^n (the number of n is m)

Does this operation has a name? Is there a book studying the nature of this operation?

Comment: “definition $N\times N \to N$ “, which is what I assume was meant, doesn’t make sense here.

Comment: Tetration, I believe. One of the hyperoperations

Comment: Yes, tetration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: This can be generalized to Knuth's up-arrow notation. A power tower with $b$ copies of $a$ is usually written as "$a\uparrow \uparrow b$". The main purpose of this function is to produce ridiculous large numbers (in most cases integers although $a$ can be any positive real number)